# Connect a row of circles to a chain in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a rather easy problem, but which I cannot seem to solve efficiently.

So I have a row of a changing number of Containers with a centered Circle, for which I used a circle icon from the Font Awesome package. And what I want to do is to connect the sides of these circles so that they form a chain.

I though of creating a custom icon, a circle with a line to the side long enough to reach the next circle.
Another option would be to use Stack and manually place a line between the cirlces, but because the number of cicles is changing, I fear the that the line will overflow the circle boundries.

Any of ou have an idea how to solve this efficiently?

Edit:
So here is a picture of what I want it to be like:
[Picture of the Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLh0S.png)

My Code right now is just

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(
         child: Center( child: CircleIcon ),
         ),
      Container(
         child: Center( child: CircleIcon ),
         ), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Container` for this. Really simple with Container.

```
Container{
    height: 50, // give any height you need
    width: 50, // give the same as height,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
       shape: BoxShape.circle,
       border: Border.all(
           color: Colors.black
       ),
    ),
}
```

Comment: I know I can use the Container to create a line, but how do I make sure the line will go from one border of the circle to another, withou overflowing on different Screens?

Comment: You can use FittedBox to make sure that the row doesn't overflow, And in the row add the circles like this, Row-> CircleContainer, HalfLine, HalfLine, CircleContainer, HalfLine, HalfLine, CircleContainer .....

Comment: Or you can always get the total width of the screen and calculate how much space you will need for the circle or the lines.